# Camel exchange failed without an exception

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

After upgrading from Camel 2.1 to 2.17 and some code modification we are having some problems with the exception handling in Camel. We send message from app A to app B. The happy flow works fine, but the unhappy flow doesn't.

We send the message to cause an exception but it is not correctly  handled in the `onexception` block.

Actually, we see the following tracelog: `ProcessTaskEx - message received`, but I don't see: `ProcessTaskEx - exception`

The exception we get from Camel is:

```
camel exchange failed without an exception: <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV>
```

Our route looks like this, any idea what the problem could be? Thank you very much for your time community! :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="switchyard://ProcessTaskEx"/>
        <log message="ProcessTaskEx - message received: ${body}" loggingLevel="DEBUG" logName="WebServiceQueues" />
        <to uri="switchyard://RequestCapacity"/>
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
             <exception>webservicequeues.utilities.WebServiceQueueException</exception>

            <log message="ProcessTaskEx - exception" loggingLevel="DEBUG" logName="WebServiceQueues" />
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="60000" maximumRedeliveryDelay="900000" retriesExhaustedLogLevel="INFO" retryAttemptedLogLevel="INFO"/>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>

            <log message="Failed after Retry.Sending ProcessTask Request to Error Queue" loggingLevel="ERROR" logName="WebServiceQueues" />
            <to uri="switchyard://ErrorProcessTaskExQueue"/>
        </onException>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fas as I remember, **faults are not handled by default**. In order to enable this a property must be set: `handleFault="true"`. It can be set for the whole Camel context or for individual routes.

Example for a route in XML:

```
<route handleFault="true">
...
</route
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed. I tested it but what happens next is very strange... It enters in a perpetual loop ignoring the maximumRedeliveries clausule:  Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-UW205584-58231-1527668174534-39-248 on ExchangeId: ID-UW205584-58231-1527668174534-39-24). On delivery attempt: 0

Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-UW205584-58231-1527668174534-39-248 on ExchangeId: ID-UW205584-58231-1527668174534-39-24). On delivery attempt: 1

And then it remains in On delivery attempt: 1 perpetually

Comment: Well, currently no idea about this. But let the community focus on it in your [other, dedicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601473/onexception-maximumredeliveries-ignored) about this :-)